# Passing variables through JQuery without onclick event for setInterval

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, setinterval

I have a simple ajax script that inserts data in database. Works great. The problem comes when I use `setInterval` to query data from `log.php` every 3 seconds I get undefined indexes. It is logical since no data is being sent. How can I avoid that? How can I pass the needed variables on `log.php` without `onclick` to run the select query successfully?

**log.php**

```
        //get variables
        $chatMessage= $_POST['chatMessage'];
        $fromUserId= $_POST['fromUserId'];
        $toUserId= $_POST['toUserId'];
        $chatStatus='1';
        $loginid_session=$fromUserId;
        $fromUser=$toUserId;


        $chatQ="SELECT * FROM ve_chat c JOIN ve_users u ON c.fromUserId=u.UserID WHERE c.toUserId= '$loginid_session' AND c.fromUserId ='$fromUser' ORDER BY sent DESC";
        $chatresult=mysqli_query($db,$chatQ);
        while($chats=mysqli_fetch_array($chatresult)){
        echo  "<div id='displayMessage'>";
        echo  "<span>" . $chats['ProfileName'] . " sent on" .$chats['sent']."</span>  : <p >".$chats['message']."</p>";
        echo  "</div>";
        }
```

**Ajax**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#buttons").click(function(){
var fromuserid = $("#fromUserId").val();
var touserid = $("#toUserId").val();
var chatMessage = $("#chatMessage").val();
// stored in database.
var dataString = 'fromUserId='+ fromuserid + '&toUserId='+ touserid + '&chatMessage='+ chatMessage;
// AJAX
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "chat.php",
data: dataString,
cache: true,
success: function(response){
   $("#displayMessage").html(response);
       $("#chatForm").trigger("reset");
}
});

return false;
});

});
 $(document).ready(function(e){ $.ajaxSetup({cache:false}); 
setInterval(function(){$('#displayMessage').load('log.php');}, 3000); 
});
    </script>
```

Comment: @E_p: what you mean?

Comment: Just wrap it into `isset`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: @E_p: isset what? Excuse my ignorance. :-/

Comment: `$chatMessage= isset($_POST['chatMessage']) ? $_POST['chatMessage'] : "default_value" ;`

Comment: @E_p: thanks. now while this removes the undefine index errors it cancels the live effect.

Comment: You can always just wrap it in `if else` instead of `?:`  and just return empty html or json or something